# Excel- dragging down formula without using transpose

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need help on using a formula so that when I use autofill and drag the cell in will link the formula vertically/horizontally like in the picture.

I don't wanna use transpose since i want the data link to the other table everytime I did some changes.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this formula

```
=OFFSET($A$3,,ROW()-ROW($A$3))
```

in `A4:A9`?

[image]

**Edit**

In this formula, `ROW($A$3)` is the row number of the cell `A3`,
that is, just a number `3`. 
Dollar prefixes in front of `A` and `3` means that this is an absolute
reference, and it will stay the same when copied to another cell(s).
Just `ROW()` means the row number of the cell, where the formula is,
so it would mean `4` for the cell `A4`, `5` for the cell `A5` and so on.
The combination `ROW()-ROW($A$3)` 
is a standard way to have a consequent numbers 
in a column of cells, so in the example,
for the cell `A4`, expression

```
ROW()-ROW($A$3)
```

means

```
4 - 3 = 1,
```

for `A5` - `=2`, and so on.

The whole formula

```
=OFFSET($A$3,,ROW()-ROW($A$3))
```

for every cell can be translated as follows:
add `ROW()-ROW($A$3)` numbers of **columns**
to the column number, where `$A$3` is (which is 1, 
since `A` is the first column), and copy the content of the cell found
to the cell, where the formula is.

For more details and examples on functions `OFFSET` and `ROW`,
check out the `Excel` help section `Lookup & Reference` functions.

Comment: yes it works, thanks a lot. btw is these a two formula and if you can explain how offset and row works?

Comment: @Jeffrey JR Villegas: Not sure what do you mean by "a two formula",
the formula is the same 
for all the cells in selection (`A4:A9` in the example).

Comment: because i saw a "row" in the index formula, sorry if i confused you,,,im still learning how index formula works and how to use it in different situations. thanks